# Using pfctl to add firewall rules at runtime WITHOUT editing /etc/pf.conf?

Tags: macos, firewall, pf

I have an OSX app that (while it is running and only while it is running) needs to make changes to the OSX packet filter (`pf`) so that it blocks or allows certain traffic. These rules should be in addition to the user's own rules in `/etc/pf.conf` - but i do not want to directly edit `/etc/pf.conf` as this is extremely intrusive.

I can do this trivially in linux using `iptables` and even in windows using `wfp` without altering any on-disk files, can i accomplish the same thing in osx with `pf` ?

Solution only has to work in `yosemite` (10.10) and above